# Identify scrollbar owner

Tags: html

I have a scrollbar which appears / disappears depending on some table filtering. That is annoying (changes the page width). I want to always show the scrollbar, by doing:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

But I do not know which div is the scrollbar belonging to. How can I find out who is the scrollbar owner?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @VikasJadhav: 7 nested django templates

Comment: @VikasJadhav let me reformulate the question: what tools can be used to identify the div if I can point to the scrollbar?

Comment: i think you need to set fixed height to table along with overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: @VikasJadhav thanks, but I know what I need to do. I do not know in which div I need to apply the style. I have applied the style in each of the divs that I thought would be responsible for the scrollbar, but I am all the time creating *new* scrollbars. That is, I do not find the div which is reponsible for the scrollbar that I want to make permanent.

Comment: Doesn't right-clicking the scrollbar and chosing "Inspect element" in the context menu reveal the element owning the scrollbar in the developer tools?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn yes ... kind of. If I select a scrollbar I am shown the element. Great! Now I get to work with the problematic scrollbar: I select it, inspect, and it shows me the `html` element. Good. Now I force it to be always displayed, with `overflow-y: scroll` and ... I get another scrollbar.

Comment: use inspect element for owner of scroll bar